# how to override page_limit of query.php file of wp-includes in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in php.

I want to override the page_limit of query.php file from the widget.
I want to display all the posts if number of posts to be displayed is not defined. I am using the following code.

```
    add_filter('post_limits', 'amr_remove_limits');
    function amr_remove_limits () {
        return ('');   
        // return an empty string so that NO limits are imposed in the query
    }
```

It is not working..
Any suggestions or references would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you tried [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits) I assume.
Your function does not have any arguments.

```
function amr_remove_limits ($limit) {
    return '';
}
```

Try the above, does not matter that you don't use the argumant

Comment: yes, i have tried that also and 
    return "";  also, still it is not working....

Comment: Did you add the $limit to the function?